# Determining Marginal Density Functions

Tags: probability

I am given

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \mathrm{where~}0 \le x \le 1\mathrm{~and~} \max(0,x-1) \le y \le \min(0,x) \\ 
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and asked to find the marginal density functions as well as the joint and marginal distribution function.

I understand that the marginal densities can be found by integrating $f(x,y)$ wrt the opposite variables, however I am unsure the limits of integration.

$f_x(x)$ would be integrated from $0$ to $x$, correct?

what would $y$ be integrated from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hint: if $x$ is some number in the interval $[0,1]$, say $0.4$, what is $\max(0,x-1)$? What is is $\min(0,x)$? What does that tell you about the valueS of $y$ where $f(0.4,y)$ equals $1$? How does the answer change if $x$ were chosen to be $0.1$? $0.98$? Are you absolutely sure you have copied the problem correctly?

Comment: Voting to close, due to the OP's absence of reaction.

Comment: Yes, the question was correctly stated. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: No it was not, right now the domain is absurd.